# Chained records - counting repetition of records

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have records about customer calls like;

```
PHONENO        CALLTIME      REP
======== =================== ===
01555444 10.03.2017 10:30:00  N <- first occurence of 01555444
02888999 12.03.2017 11:40:20  N
01555444 15.03.2017 18:22:33  Y <- repeated 1st time 01555444
03666777 18.03.2017 20:36:44  N
01555444 19.03.2017 08:15:47  Y <- repeated 2nd time 01555444
01555444 30.03.2017 22:18:30  N <- first occurence of 01555444 (gap more than 10 days)
```

If a call occures within next 10 from previous call (from the same phone number), then it is assumed a repeated call (assigned 'Y' in column REP).

Now I want to have the table like this with number of repetitions:

```
PHONENO        CALLTIME      REP REPNO
======== =================== === =====
01555444 10.03.2017 10:30:00  N    0
02888999 12.03.2017 11:40:20  N    0
01555444 15.03.2017 18:22:33  Y    1
03666777 18.03.2017 20:36:44  N    0
01555444 19.03.2017 08:15:47  Y    2
01555444 30.03.2017 22:18:30  N    0
```

REPNO represents the number of (chained) call repetition (within 10 days).

How to calculate this?

Comment: `Mysql` or `Oracle`?

Comment: Oracle preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it that uses the [tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) method to identify the groups of repeated rows:

```
WITH cust_calls AS (SELECT '01555444' phoneno, to_date('10/03/2017 10:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') calltime FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '02888999' phoneno, to_date('12/03/2017 11:40:20', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') calltime FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '01555444' phoneno, to_date('15/03/2017 18:22:33', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') calltime FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '03666777' phoneno, to_date('18/03/2017 20:36:44', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') calltime FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '01555444' phoneno, to_date('19/03/2017 08:15:47', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') calltime FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '01555444' phoneno, to_date('30/03/2017 22:18:30', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') calltime FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '01555444' phoneno, to_date('30/04/2017 23:42:31', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') calltime FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '01555444' phoneno, to_date('05/05/2017 16:35:41', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') calltime FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '01555444' phoneno, to_date('20/05/2017 21:20:52', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') calltime FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT '02888999' phoneno, to_date('12/03/2017 11:45:20', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') calltime FROM dual),
  -- end of mimicking a table with your sample data in it. You do not need the above subquery, since you already have the table.
   initial_info AS (SELECT phoneno,
                           calltime,
                           CASE WHEN calltime - LAG(calltime) OVER (PARTITION BY phoneno ORDER BY calltime) <= 10 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END rep_row
                    FROM   cust_calls),
    middle_info AS (SELECT phoneno,
                           calltime,
                           rep_row rep,
                           CASE WHEN rep_row = 'Y' THEN
                                     row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY phoneno ORDER BY calltime)
                                       - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY phoneno, rep_row ORDER BY calltime)
                           END rep_grp
                    FROM   initial_info)
SELECT phoneno,
       calltime,
       rep,
       CASE WHEN rep_grp is not NULL THEN
                 row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY phoneno, rep_grp ORDER BY calltime)
       END repno
FROM   middle_info
ORDER BY phoneno, calltime;

PHONENO  CALLTIME            REP      REPNO
-------- ------------------- --- ----------
01555444 05/05/2017 16:35:41 Y            1
01555444 10/03/2017 10:30:00 N   
01555444 15/03/2017 18:22:33 Y            1
01555444 19/03/2017 08:15:47 Y            2
01555444 20/05/2017 21:20:52 N   
01555444 30/03/2017 22:18:30 N   
01555444 30/04/2017 23:42:31 N   
02888999 12/03/2017 11:40:20 N   
02888999 12/03/2017 11:45:20 Y            1
03666777 18/03/2017 20:36:44 N
```

This works by first identifying the repeated rows by comparing the current row's calltime with the previous row's calltime and deciding if it's within 10 days or not. If you already have this info, you can skip this step and go straight to the next.

Next, we use the tabibitosan method to compare consecutive rows over all rows for the same phoneno and over all rows where rep_row is 'Y'.

Then we can use the number output by the previous step to partition the phoneno rows up even further, and then apply the row_number() analytic function to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this expertise. I have one additional question related to this matter; is it possible that partition in `PARTITION BY` clause consist of more that one column? Here I look for the same phone number and that's `PARTITION BY phoneno`. In my case customers are same if `phoneno OR assetid` between them are same. So how to define partitions where phoneno or assets are the same?

Comment: It's hard to say without more sample data from you showing your actual scenario. However, the `PARTITION BY` clause of an analytic function works in the same way as the `GROUP BY` clause in an aggregate query. If you can specify what makes a set of rows a group, then you can use that in the `PARTITION BY` clause. Maybe in your case, you need something like `PARTITION BY phoneno, assetid` or maybe it's more like `PARTITION BY COALESCE(phoneno, assetid)`.